# Overloading in child class, unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, binding, static, overriding, overloading

The below program prints ParentClass a() -

```
public class StaticBindingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParentClass p = new ChildClass();

        p.a("abc");
    }       
}

class ParentClass{

    public void a(Object o){
        System.out.println("ParentClass a()");  
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{

    public void a(String s){
        System.out.println("ChildClass a()");   
    }
}
```

However, if I change ParentClass a() to accept String, the program prints Childclass a(). Why? -

```
package com.my.test;

public class StaticBindingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParentClass p = new ChildClass();

        p.a("abc");
    }       
}

class ParentClass{

    public void a(String o){
        System.out.println("ParentClass a()");  
    }
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{

    public void a(String s){
        System.out.println("ChildClass a()");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which *overload* of a method to call is decided at compile time. Which *implementation* of a method to call is decided at runtime.

In the first situation, `ChildClass` has essentially two overloads of `a`. One that accepts a `String` and one that accepts `Object`.

Your variable `p`'s compile time type is `ParentClass`. The compiler does not actually know it is actually a `ChildClass`. That has to wait till runtime. So the compiler looks into `ParentClass` and see that there is only one overload of `a` in `ParentClass` so it decides to call that overload, hence the output.

In the second situation, there is 1 overload, but 2 implementations for `a` in `ChildClass`.

The compiler sees your `p` as `ParentClass` as usual and this time, it chooses the overload that accepts a `String`, which is the only one to choose here. Now at runtime, `a` is called. Since `p` is actually a `ChildClass` instance, it calls the implementation in `ChildClass`, hence the output.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the child class then [`Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) the parent's implementation. There is a brief overview of how things are processed when you define a method with the same signature as a method in a superclass :

[image]

In a subclass, you can **overload** the methods (as in your first example) inherited from the superclass. Such overloaded methods *neither hide nor override* the superclass instance methods—they are new methods, unique to the subclass.

---

When overriding a method, you might want to use the `@Override` annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a method in the superclass. ***If, for some reason, the compiler detects that the method does not exist in one of the superclasses, then it will generate an error***.